# JCheckBoxMenuItem only one selected

Tags: java, swing, optimization, jcheckbox, jmenu

So I want to have a JMenu Level with three JCheckBoxMenuItem like Easy, normal and expert.
Of course, only one can be checked and if one is checked, it can't be unchecked (enabled(false)) because it's the only one.
I want when one JCheck is checked, all others are unchecked.

So it seems easy, but the only solution I found is to do it with a lot of "if" conditions.

Is there a way to do it with a better algorithm ?

Comment: I think the best way to do this, is indeed making use of "if" statements. You could also use JRadioButtonMenuItem, which creates those bullet selecting things, from which you can select only one at a time.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you'd be better off using a JRadioButton since check boxes are generally used for multiple-choice options and radio buttons for a single selection out of many. JRadioButtons can be grouped together using a ButtonGroup which allows only one selected at a time.

Comment: The things is I can only have type of JMenuItem, so I can't use ButtonGroup

Comment: In that case, the code below may be more appropriate. Looks like it'll have to be a lot of if statements unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

    if (e.getSource() == cb1 && cb1.isSelected()) {
        cb2.setSelected(false);
        cb3.setSelected(false);
    } else if (e.getSource() == cb2 && cb2.isSelected()) {
        cb3.setSelected(false);
        cb1.setSelected(false);
    } else if (e.getSource() == cb3 && cb3.isSelected()) {
        cb1.setSelected(false);
        cb2.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i just put all my JCheckBoxMenuItems in an array 
and every time i select a JCheckBoxMenuItem i call this method

```
public void clearCheckBoxes(){
for (JCheckBoxMenuItem arrayCB1 : arrayCB) {
if (arrayCB1 != cb) {
arrayCB1.setSelected(false);
} else {
arrayCB1.setSelected(true);
}
        }
}
```

The annoying part was having to manualy put them in the array,maybe the jMenu class has a method that returns the complete array but i didnt bother looking

```
        arrayCB[0]=bridgeCB;
        arrayCB[1]=swampCB;
        arrayCB[2]=flowerCB;
        arrayCB[3]=MountainCB;
        arrayCB[4]=Mountain2CB;
        arrayCB[5]=forestCB;
        arrayCB[6]=parisCB;
        arrayCB[7]=roadCB;
        arrayCB[8]=waveCB;
        arrayCB[9]=lakeCB;
```

just in case , this is how you create the array

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem [] arrayCB=new JCheckBoxMenuItem[10];
```

i dont know about that lots of if statements way of doing it