# How can I add a check mark next to a menu item that has been selected?

Tags: java, swing, menuitem

I have the following code which shows a menu called "Options" and under it are the menu items "AI Mode" and "Player Mode". I just want to know how I can mark each one of these with a check mark when chosen.

```
package com.sean.breakout.menu;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MenuBar() {
    add(createOptionsMenu());   
}

private JMenu createOptionsMenu() {
    JMenu fileOptions = new JMenu("Options");
    JMenuItem aiMode = new JMenuItem("AI Mode");
    JMenuItem playerMode = new JMenuItem("Player Mode");
    fileOptions.add(aiMode);
    fileOptions.add(playerMode);
    return fileOptions;
}

}
```

Comment: You mean something like [`JCheckBoxMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html).  See [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more details

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer can easily be obtained by reading the [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) tutorial, which includes code examples

Comment: -1, `Ok, but what if I wanted to make it so that when one box is checked, the other one is automatically unchecked?` - read the tutorial. You've been given the link to the tutorial twice!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `aiMode` and `playerMode` to `JCheckBoxMenuItems` for this purpose. For example:

```
JCheckBoxMenuItem aiMode = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("AI Mode");
fileOptions.add(aiMode);
//same goes for playerMode
```

Documentation for `JCheckBoxMenuItem` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JCheckBoxMenuItem.html).

**Edit:** Here is another SO post on how to select only one item at a time: [JCheckBoxMenuItem only one selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720400/jcheckboxmenuitem-only-one-selected)

Comment: (1+) The Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) contains a working example.